# Flutter: Failed to find assets path for "flutter_assets" error

Tags: flutter

I am trying to embed a Flutter module into iOS app.
But when i tap the button that will show the FlutterViewController, a blank screen shows up and this is printed on the console:

```
Failed to find assets path for "flutter_assets"
[VERBOSE-2:engine.cc(111)] Engine run configuration was invalid.
[VERBOSE-2:FlutterViewController.mm(462)] Could not launch engine with configuration.
flutter: Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:54632/
```

- I followed this tutorial https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps
- I added a FLUTTER_ROOT to my build settings
- I tried running the app with a `FlutterAppDelegate` and also a `FlutterViewController`
- My `flutter doctor` says nothing is wrong.

Comment: Can you take a look at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20777 and seeing if any of the comment there help you?

Comment: Thank you jasmedin, I will post it there! Best regards.

Comment: See also this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61144408/failed-to-find-assets-path-for-frameworks-app-framework-flutter-assets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by changing to master channel and it solved.

- To change channel use the cli `flutter channel master`
- After that I deleted the ".ios" folder inside the flutter project and run a `flutter build --ios` to force Flutter to re-generate the .ios folder.
- Then I did a `pod install` in my native iOS app.

Comment: Word of warning for future readers: this is true today, but at some point this will work outside the master channel!  It's actively being worked on right now though, so some of the latest/greatest stuff is only in master right now.

Comment: Hey Dan, you have an Idea when the current master (10/24/18) will be available on beta?

Comment: It's about monthly - should be sometime in November.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways this could happen that I've seen:

1. You're missing your `flutter_assets` folder completely
2. You're trying to use AOT compiled Flutter app (e.g. profile or release mode) with a debug engine build.
3. You're trying to use JIT compiled Flutter app (debug) with a profile/release engine.

It sounds like you're missing your `flutter_assets`.  Please follow the steps on the Add2App wiki.

I'm actively working on making this process easier - unfortunately, there are a lot of manual steps right now that are easy to get wrong.

Comment: Let's continue the topic in the  flutter's github issue. After the problem get's fixed I post here the solution to this specific problem, so others can find help here.

Comment: @DanField do you have any ETA on when this process will be easier?  Thanks

Comment: Some of the work I've done has landed at this point and the wiki page has been updated.  What did you have in mind?