# Failed to find assets path for "Frameworks/App.framework/flutter_assets"

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart

I'm trying to run my flutter app on the simulator ( iPhone 8 ) but when the app lunches all I get is a blank white screen. like this:

[image]

Terminal output is:

```
Running pod install...                                             40.0s
Running Xcode build...                                                  

 ├─Assembling Flutter resources...                          20.4s
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                        57.0s
Xcode build done.                                           288.8s
        path: satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en1
Failed to find assets path for "Frameworks/App.framework/flutter_assets"
Configuring the default Firebase app...
        path: satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en1
        path: satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en1
Configured the default Firebase app __FIRAPP_DEFAULT.
[VERBOSE-2:engine.cc(127)] Engine run configuration was invalid.
[VERBOSE-2:shell.cc(437)] Could not launch engine with configuration.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging
to ensure proper integration.                                           
Syncing files to device iPhone 8...                                     
10,195ms (!)
```

I'm using the stable version of flutter `1.12.13+hotfix.9`, and this issue appears only on ios building.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've just managed to solve this issue. I've just followed advise https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29974 and added 
***"$FLUTTER_ROOT/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh" embed***
to Run script 
[Run script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LH5RX.png)
After rebuilding App.framework folder has been added to build directory and problem has gone. 
Hope this will help someone else.

Comment: Julia, your approach is the best!

Comment: Thank you this worked! Not sure why this happened in the first place

Comment: So thankful for this - after AGES trying to get it working! In case it helps anybody else: I *also* had a second issue which coincidentally was *also* causing a white screen. I diagnosed that one by running `flutter run` in the command line to get at the *real* Flutter error logs, then with that resolved this solution here made it work from Xcode too.

Comment: Out of interest, how on earth did you discover this, and how are normal people meant to know to do this?? I couldn't find any reference in the docs about needing to manually add this?

Answer (score 7):

You can follow the instructions in https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ios-project-migration

Particularly the build phase:

```
/bin/sh "$FLUTTER_ROOT/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh" embed
/bin/sh "$FLUTTER_ROOT/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh" thin
```

You can see more here:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/52084#issuecomment-600768772

Comment: Hello, it is executed under the terminal of the root directory of the vscode project, thank you

Answer (score 1):

First, you should write in your android studio terminal this command:

- **rm -rf ios/Flutter/App.framework**
- Then in Xcode select **TARGETS** then select **Runner**
- After that choose the **Build Phases** from Middle Top options
- Then Open the **Thin Binary**
- Remove the script inside with

/bin/sh "$FLUTTER_ROOT/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh" embed

/bin/sh "$FLUTTER_ROOT/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh" thin

That's Worked for me, Hopefully, work for you also :-)

Further read :
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ios-project-migration

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I need to uncheck the build flag "For install build only" in Build Phrases -> Run Script