# Failed to find assets path for "Frameworks/App.framework/flutter_assets" on macOS

Tags: flutter

IOS app stuck at white screen. I have tried applying all the methods provided in the links below :

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29974

[failed-to-find-assets-path-for-frameworks-app-framework-flutter-assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61144408/failed-to-find-assets-path-for-frameworks-app-framework-flutter-assets)

[ios-project-migration](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ios-project-migration)

Besides this I also tried switching to channels **master**, **stable**, and **beta** followed by `flutter upgrade`

**The error below is showing up with a white screen on ios.**

```
Runner[1469:358771] Failed to find assets path for "Frameworks/App.framework/flutter_assets"
2020-09-25 11:23:36.139301+0300 Runner[1469:358771] Metal API Validation Enabled
2020-09-25 11:23:36.255401+0300 Runner[1469:359037] flutter: Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:60092/RGJQkAJoLdQ=/
2020-09-25 11:23:36.267284+0300 Runner[1469:359021] 6.26.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to NO. Follow the instructions at:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging
to ensure proper integration.
2020-09-25 11:23:36.268203+0300 Runner[1469:359016] 6.26.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60600000 started
2020-09-25 11:23:36.268648+0300 Runner[1469:359016] 6.26.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see some link here)
2020-09-25 11:23:36.523458+0300 Runner[1469:358771] WF: === Starting WebFilter logging for process Runner
2020-09-25 11:23:36.523517+0300 Runner[1469:358771] WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile: {
    filterBlacklist =     (
    );
    filterWhitelist =     (
    );
    restrictWeb = 1;
    useContentFilter = 0;
    useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
    whitelistEnabled = 0;
}
2020-09-25 11:23:36.523578+0300 Runner[1469:358771] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-09-25 11:23:36.524278+0300 Runner[1469:358771] [Firebase/Crashlytics] Version 4.1.1
2020-09-25 11:23:36.527135+0300 Runner[1469:359023] 6.26.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement
2020-09-25 11:23:36.529562+0300 Runner[1469:359023] 6.26.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS031025] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
2020-09-25 11:23:36.539596+0300 Runner[1469:359021] 6.26.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled
2020-09-25 11:23:36.570952+0300 Runner[1469:358771] Failed to find assets path for "Frameworks/App.framework/flutter_assets"
2020-09-25 11:23:36.572494+0300 Runner[1469:358771] Failed to find assets path for "Frameworks/App.framework/flutter_assets"
2020-09-25 11:23:36.573146+0300 Runner[1469:358771] database path: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/3875121B-A000-4B67-96A7-DEE8B14FAFB8/Runner.app/Frameworks/flutter_downloader.framework/FlutterDownloaderDatabase.bundle/download_tasks.sql
2020-09-25 11:23:36.573321+0300 Runner[1469:358771] MAXIMUM_CONCURRENT_TASKS = 1
2020-09-25 11:23:36.580536+0300 Runner[1469:358771] init NSURLSession with id: com.vt.vt.download.background.1601022216.573343
2020-09-25 11:23:36.580575+0300 Runner[1469:358771] AllFilesDownloadedMessage: All files have been downloaded
2020-09-25 11:23:36.582748+0300 Runner[1469:359026] [VERBOSE-2:engine.cc(134)] Engine run configuration was invalid.
2020-09-25 11:23:36.582785+0300 Runner[1469:359026] [VERBOSE-2:shell.cc(486)] Could not launch engine with configuration.
2020-09-25 11:23:36.833783+0300 Runner[1469:358771] [VERBOSE-2:FlutterObservatoryPublisher.mm(115)] Failed to register observatory port with mDNS.
2020-09-25 11:23:37.016415+0300 Runner[1469:358771] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}>
2020-09-25 11:23:37.016456+0300 Runner[1469:358771] [ProcessSuspension] 0x10fcccbc0 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS Background assertion 'WebProcess Background Assertion' for process with PID 1470, error: Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}
2020-09-25 11:23:43.788525+0300 Runner[1469:359042] [connection] nw_resolver_start_query_timer_block_invoke [C3] Query fired: did not receive all answers in time for firebasedynamiclinks-ipv4.googleapis.com:443
```

### flutter doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.22.0-10.0.pre.356, on Mac OS X 10.15.6 19G2021
    x86_64, locale en-ET)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.48.2)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
```

**Incase something is wrong with my build phases here is what it looks like**

[image]

**Podfile looks like this**

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end

  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        # Here are some configurations automatically generated by flutter

        # You can remove unused permissions here
        # for more infomation: https://github.com/BaseflowIT/flutter-permission-handler/blob/develop/permission_handler/ios/Classes/PermissionHandlerEnums.h
        # e.g. when you don't need camera permission, just add 'PERMISSION_CAMERA=0'
        config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
          '$(inherited)',

          ## dart: PermissionGroup.calendar
           'PERMISSION_EVENTS=0',

          ## dart: PermissionGroup.reminders
           'PERMISSION_REMINDERS=0',

          ## dart: PermissionGroup.contacts
           'PERMISSION_CONTACTS=0',

          ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
          # 'PERMISSION_CAMERA=0',

          ## dart: PermissionGroup.microphone
          # 'PERMISSION_MICROPHONE=0',

          ## dart: PermissionGroup.speech
           'PERMISSION_SPEECH_RECOGNIZER=0',

          ## dart: PermissionGroup.photos
          # 'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=0',

          ## dart: [PermissionGroup.location, PermissionGroup.locationAlways, PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]
           'PERMISSION_LOCATION=0',

          ## dart: PermissionGroup.notification
          # 'PERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS=0',

          ## dart: PermissionGroup.mediaLibrary
           'PERMISSION_MEDIA_LIBRARY=0',

          ## dart: PermissionGroup.sensors
           'PERMISSION_SENSORS=0'
        ]

      end
    end
end
```