# Flutter on OSX M1 Mac gives error on xcode_backend.sh, about xcode project version when building for simulator

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm on an M1 Mac Mini, Monterey 12.0.1, with XCode 13.1 & it's command-line tools and freshly-installed Flutter MacOS 2.8.0.  I create a base Flutter project with

```
flutter create appname
```

When I do "flutter run" in the ios folder (in the parent folder it launches ok in Chrome), I get the message:

```
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13.
```

I tried it with the simulator running, and not.  It looks like the Runner XCode project build stages runs a script, xcode_backend.sh. I also tried loading the project in the XCode UI to build and get 'Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code' on that script.

If I go and run this script directly, from the project folder of the ios folder:

```
guy@Guys-Mac-mini ios % /bin/sh "$FLUTTER_ROOT/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh"
```

I get the message:

```
error: Your Xcode project is incompatible with this version of Flutter. Run "rm -rf ios/Runner.xcodeproj" and "flutter create ." to regenerate.
```

I tried the steps indicated, which I also found on Google, and removed the folder and regenerated the project, but the same message is appearing.  (I did export the FLUTTER_ROOT environment variable, both in the shell and it's also defined in the XCode project settings.

I can build and run the flutter apps to Chrome, but not for the iOS simulator.  I also have no problem building and running Swift apps I've coded on the simulator.

I got my Windows and Android setup running in minutes, but on the M1 Mac it's been hours without success.  Any ideas?

I'm a developer with decent of experience, but this is my first stab at Flutter and cross-platform (other than Xamarin).  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Some additional notes:  Flutter doctor indicates that there are no problems, and notes XCode 13.1 in it's checked list.  I have researched this on google and found recommendations to remove the script from the build steps, to remove and re-create the project with flutter (as mentioned in post), and to verify that cocoapods was installed, and other items like ffi, Rosetta updates, to install and accept xcodebuild license.

Answer (score 0):

I can't fully explain it, but the problem I was having was related to my having the project files on an SMB share I was accessing from the Mac.

I setup the project on an SMB share so I could access it from my Windows and Mac workstations.  I found that any flutter project on that share would fail compilation.

To test this, I created a new flutter app on my Mac Documents folder, comiled and ran it succesfully in the iOS simulator using 'flutter run'.  When I moved that project to the SMB share and tried to run it, I got the compilation error again, and it wouldn't run (I also tried clean and run).  I moved the project back to the local drive Documents folder, and was able to run it again.

I also noticed that the Mac access to the SMB share is painfully slow, though I tried a required_signon fixes from
https://kb.synology.com/en-us/DSM/tutorial/What_can_I_do_to_fix_slow_SMB_file_transfers_on_OS_X_10_11_5 but it didn't help.

I had even tried to factory reset my Mac, and I thought that fixed it, but it was only because I hadn't connected to the share yet, and made a test project on the local drive.

PS: I don't expect to use the exact same Flutter project between the Mac and Windows workstations because of paths and SDK locations, but I am using it as a convenient place for transfering the source files.

Comment: You really should be using `git` to access your project across multiple machines instead of SMB. SMB will eventually give you huge headaches regardless of which computers you are trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

My team was able to solve this by supplying an absolute path to the xcode_backend script in a run phase and running it. Running it once seemed to be enough and we could remove it thereafter:

```
/bin/sh "/absolute-path-to-flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh" thin
/bin/sh "/absolute-path-to-flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh" embed
```

Comment: you can read more about it in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61144408/failed-to-find-assets-path-for-frameworks-app-framework-flutter-assets

Comment: and this issue may have something to do with this? https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ios-project-migration